# Is it necessary to check whether the current thread is the main thread or not before dispatching to it asynchronously?

Tags: objective-c, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Is it really necessary to check whether the current thread is the main thread or not before dispatching to it asynchronously? Is there any advantage in performance or something else?

I know that dispatching synchronously from the same queue results in a deadlock. But do I really need to check the current Thread like someone did in the following Snippet?

```
+ (void)dispatchOnMainThread:(void (^)(void))task
    {
        if ([NSThread isMainThread]) // Is this necessary?
        {
            task();
        }
        else
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), task);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it is UI task so yes it's depends.

Comment: I have also met that code. Personally I prefer just to dispatch in main queue if I am not 100% sure, that I am in main thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But do i really need to check the current Thread like someone did in the following Snippet

Not really. If you're already on the main thread, then when your code comes to an end, your `dispatch_async` block will be dispatched. So there might be a slight delay because we need the current run loop / transaction to come to an end, but it won't be noticeable.

I use `dispatch_async` to the main thread all the time as a way of making sure I'm on the main thread in situations where I'm uncertain (KVO callbacks, for example). No harm, no foul. It's just a form of insurance.

Comment: Thanks Matt. This is the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check whether you are on the main thread, dispatch_async just puts the task into a queue and returns. Perfectly safe.

On the other hand, if you check whether you are on the main thread and execute the task directly, then don't call your method dispatchOnMainThread, because it doesn't dispatch. Application behaviour can change because of this. I'd call it runOnMainThread, and I'd make it a plain C function. And it's nicer for debugging.